# regex to make sure safe input. no script injections html etc?

Tags: php, regex, validation

Im looking for a regex to make sure noboy haxes in stuff I dont want in a guesbook I made in PHP. Such as, scripts, sqlinjections, html etc. But still I want the users to be able to use as many chars as they can (ex :)(/?!.,"&-_) without doing the site less safe.

ideas of how that regex would look like?

Comment: +1 @thatidiotguy - That is the best regex I've ever seen ;-)

Comment: Note that `htmlspecialchars` helps prevent XSS, not SQL injection. To prevent SQL injection, use prepared statements. To prevent CRSF, you can do a little research.

Comment: Make it an answer @thatidiotguy ... :)

Comment: You can also use `filter_var` and `http://htmlpurifier.org/`

Comment: @Fridak There is no reason to delete them. If you output them through `htmlspecialchars` they will not interpreted as HTML, so there is no danger.

Comment: @Wrikken Not sure if its worthy of answer material, but ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
htmlspecialchars($output)
```

Note that `htmlspecialchars` helps prevent XSS, not SQL injection. To prevent SQL injection, use prepared statements. To prevent CRSF, you can do a little research.

Comment: yeah of course. awesome! i thought there were more to prevent sql injections then the prepared statements but i trust u know!:) thx

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO or MySQLI with prepared and bound statements. If you do it right, you won't need to worry about Regex - unless you really want to go over-kill with security ;)